# Xamarin.Forms unresponsive in Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

When I create a new Xamarin.Forms project (PCL), Visual Studio becomes unresponsive, only  accepting clicks and key presses every few seconds with large pauses in between. No other project types that I've tried have this issue. Have you encountered this problem or have a workaround?

*Update: Deleting the iOS project from File Explorer seems to have fixed the issue but this means I can't target iOS. Also, native iOS projects freeze as well. Could this be an iOS thing?

Comment: When you create a Xamarin.Forms project visual studio can take a while to create all the projects for each platform, especially if your PC is on the slower side, but once it's created you should just be able to unload any projects you aren't running at the time. This should fix your issue with it locking up that or one suggestion is you create a new solution file for each platform that uses the same PCL project but only has the iOS, Android, or UWP project with it.

Comment: @Nick I allowed it to sit for 1+ hours but no change and it only affects Xamarin: forms previewer, axml designer, and everything iOS.
I'm running on windows 10 Pro (64-bit), 8GB ram, Intel Core i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz 2.40GHz

Comment: It may just be the latest version of Xamarin, and I haven't updated in a while, but in the past usually unloading a project solved it

Answer (score 0):

Since installing the recent Visual Studio 2017 updates, the problem seems to have been resolved.